# Use one virtualenv between many releases

Tags: python, deployment, virtualenv

I have a script set up that checks out the current version of our codebase for each deploy, so we can roll it back in case it breaks. So far I have been creating a new virtualenv in each checkout directory, but it is becoming time consuming to build the packages each time, especially since they hardly change.

Is there a way to share the virtualenv between many directories that are similar?

Comment: Would that actually work for virtualenv? Haven't experimented with it.

Comment: for me it worked. You can also try ".pth" files approach. Both will require you to implement deployment procedure that is more than "virtualenv --no-site-packages venv && source venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt". You will need to use references to existing virtualenv packages as default, optionally replaced by newly installed packages. I think you may utilize "-U" option for "pip install" somehow.